# Regex expressions to match text between first comma and the comma before the first number

Tags: regex, csv

I have a csv file with all UK areas (43000 rows).
However, even though the fields are separated with commas, they are not enclosed with anything, hence if the field has commas within its contents, import to a database fails.

Fortunately, there is only one field that has commas within its content.
I need a regular expression that I could use to select this field on all rows.

Here is an example of data:

```
Aberaman,Rhondda, Cynon, Taf (Rhondda, Cynon, Taff),51.69N,03.43W,SO0101
Aberangell,Powys,52.67N,03.71W,SH8410
```

This should look like:

```
Aberaman,"Rhondda, Cynon, Taf (Rhondda, Cynon, Taff)",51.69N,03.43W,SO0101
Aberangell,"Powys",52.67N,03.71W,SH8410
```

So I need to basically select the second field, which is between the first comma and the comma just before the first number.

I will use sublime text 2 to perform this regex search.

Comment: why your second example wouldn't look like `Aberangell,"Powys",52.67N,03.71W,SH8410`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sublime text2 supports `\K`,

**Regex:**

```
^[^,]*,\K(.*?)(?=,\d)
```

**Replacement string:**

```
"\1"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iE2xM4/5)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start of a line.
- `[^,]*` Matches any character not of comma zero or more times.
- `,` Literal comma.
- `\K` Previously matched characters would be discarded.
- `(.*?)(?=,\d)` Matches any character zeror or more times which must be followed by `,` and a number. `?` after `*` does a reluctant match.

Comment: It worked great! Thank you. Also thanks for the explanation. Always nice to understand how it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with capturing groups. Simply substitute it with `$1"$2"$3` or `\1"\2"\3`

```
^(\w+,)([^\d]*)(,.*)$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aK7xH8/2)

---

You can do it in `Notepad++` as well.

Find what:  `^(\w+,)([^\d]*)(,.*)$`

Replace with: `$1"$2"$3`

Answer (score 1):

A regex which should be able to solve your problem is:

```
^.*?,(.*?),\d+
```

This matches 
anything (non-greedy) up to first comma (which will not be included in result)
then anything up to second comma (which will be in a group)
and additional condition is that there has to be a number after second comma

So your group is in $1